# Is there a way to append r' to a sting in Python dynamically?

Tags: python, r, checksum, rawstring

I am new to Python and I am working to calculate checksum of a string that has backslashes (). I was able to come up with a logic to calculate the checksum but that function needs the string to be in raw format (r') to calculate the correct checksum. However this function will be invoked by another function and I will not be able to convert the string to raw string manually. Can someone please help me on how to achieve this dynamically.

Here is the string:

```
raw_message1 = '=K+8\\\08|'
```

This string has 3 backslashes however it shows only 2 after saving and this string may vary again so replacing after processing will not help.

And when I print the result:

```
print(message1)
=K+8\ 8|
```

What I need is to have something that retains the backslashes as is. I cannot go for any other character as every character has its own ASCII value and checksum would differ. I tried all the other options mentioned before and see different result for each case.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the string as so:

```
message1 = r'=K+8\\08|'
```

This should make the string message1 be in raw form.

Let me know if this helps. I don't really understand what you mean by converting to raw string manually and converting it dynamically. This is the most I can help with for now.

Comment: I tried converting a raw string manually and is working fine without any issues. However, I am looking way to do this dynamically. I mean the string will be an input to my function and I should be able to calculate checksum treating these backslashes as literals

Answer (score 0):

All the `r` prefix does is manually add backslashes so you don't have to, it doesn't "magically" retain the backslashes, instead it replaces them with double backslashes so they are interpreted as single backslashes.

Look at the following example:

```py
>>> s = r"\rando\\\mst\ri\ngo\\flet\ters"
>>> s
'\\rando\\\\\\mst\\ri\\ngo\\\\flet\\ters'
>>> print(s)
\rando\\\mst\ri\ngo\\flet\ters
>>>
```

The string actually contains double backslashes and when printed they are interpreted as single backslashes.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help out. What you said is true but the concern here is how to add r" dynamically

Comment: Oh I see, I think (not 100% sure), that this is not possible, at least not easily. When you create a non-raw string that has a `\n` inside, python will immediately see that and say "ah that's a newline" and convert the two characters `\`, `n` to a single newline character. To un-convert, you would have to reconstruct the string replacing all the possible escaped characters with their non-escaped equivalent, i.e. `\n`->`\\n`, `\x00`-> `\\0` etc. which can be very VERY tedious. It's better to return a raw string from the function, if possible. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for you comments Alex, even the replacing will not help me as the  number of slashes may vary '\' :(